# Integration including greater integer function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Need help with this integral I=$\int_{0}^{9 \times 10^6} (1-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x})$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes greatest integer function.
I have tried breaking it into fractional part but couldn't get any good approach and also if i go for breaking the GIF function where ever it is integer...it comes out to be 3001 points in the given range of number in the integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every integer $n$ from $0$ to $3\cdot10^3-1$,
$$\int_{n^2}^{(n+1)^2}\left(1-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\right)dx=\left[x-2n\sqrt x\right]_{n^2}^{(n+1)^2}=1$$
hence
$$\int_0^{9\cdot10^6}\left(1-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\right)dx=3\cdot10^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{9 \times 10^6} \left(1-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\right)dx=9\times10^6-\int_{0}^{9 \times 10^6} \left(\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\right)dx$$ Put $x=t^2$ so $dx=2tdt$ and the second integral becomes
$$2\int_{0}^{3 \times 10^3}\lfloor(t)\rfloor dt= 2\sum_{n=0}^{n=3\times10^3}=2\frac{3\times10^3(3\times10^3+1)}{2}$$
So $$\int_{0}^{9 \times 10^6} \left(1-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\right)dx=-3000$$

Comment: The integrand being $\ge0$, your $-3000<0$ is necessarily wrong. The mistake comes from your $n=3\times10^3$ in the upper limit of $\sum$, instead of my $n=3\times10^3-1$. The final result is$$9\cdot10^6-2\frac{(3\cdot10^3-1)3\cdot10^3}2={\color{red}+}3\cdot10^3.$$